# For what reasons a bank deny basic saving account

Tags: banking, bank-account, malaysia

I applied to open a basic saving account with Citibank few days back in Malaysia (I'm not a Malaysian citizen, nor I am an American). I work in Malaysia, and one of the strict conditions of the bank to open account, is to have a work permit valid for 12 months at least. My work permit is valid for 13 months when I applied, and my employment letter (I attached) states I'm a permanent employee. However, two days later, the bank called me to inform me my application was not approved. When I asked what is the reason, she said it is management decision and they cannot disclose it.

I'm baffled as what could be the reason. I read this thread [thread](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47227/why-would-a-bank-refuse-to-open-a-bank-account), I could not use the advised website as it seems it only applies to American citizens with social security number (I wonder if there is any equivalent website for none Americans). My salary is higher than the average in this country for my position, and in fact I never had a credit card, never took a loan (I always preferred to pay cash). I've been living in Malaysia for four years, and never had any banking trouble with other local bank.

Is there any way to find out the reason.

Comment: Just to be clear, you already have one or more bank accounts at a different bank?

Comment: @NotMe yes I do